# how to get full statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

i wonder how to get full query statement in postgresql, when i set log_statement = 'all' in data/postgresql.conf, i can track the query record in log/ directory, but they log the query is:

```
LOG: Select * from table where id = $1
DETAIL: parameters: $1 = 55,
```

when there just a small amount param, that is clear. But if many params exist in that query,
that maybe frastrated me. if any some setting in postgresql that i need set, so i can directly get full statement such as

```
Select * from table where id = 55
```

Comment: check the extension `pgaudit`, it might log what you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get that in the log, because that is not what arrives at the server. However, it should be easy to write a Perl (or other) script that reformats a log like that.